# Is the inequality $\sum_{i} p_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq \frac{\sum_{i} p_i a_i}{\sum_{i} p_i b_i}$ true?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p_i \in [0,1]$ and $\sum_{i} p_i = 1$, and furthermore let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be positive real numbers. Is the inequality
$$
\sum_{i} p_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq \frac{\sum_{i} p_i a_i}{\sum_{i} p_i b_i}$$
true?

Comment: Your inequality is linear with respect to, say, $a_1$. And the coefficient of $a_1$ in LHS may be both more and less than in RHS. Thus, without additional restrictions there is no chance to be true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. This reads
$${\mathbb E}[f(a,b)]\le f({\mathbb E}[a,b])$$
for an arbitrary discrete probability. This is true if and only if $f$ is a concave function (Jenssen Inequality). But $f(x,y)=\frac xy$ is not concave (nor convex).

You might prefer the convex function $g(x,y)=\frac{x^2}y$, for which we thus have
$${\mathbb E}\left[\frac{a^2}b\right]\ge \frac{{\mathbb E}[a]^2}{{\mathbb E}[b]}.$$

Comment: By $f({\mathbb E}[a,b])$ you mean $f({\mathbb E}[a],{\mathbb E}[b])$?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch. Yes I do.

Comment: Nice answer. Without graphing them I never would have thought that $x^2/y$ is convex while $x/y$ isn't!

Comment: @YaakovBaruch. The convexity of $x^2/y$ over ${\mathbb R}\times(0,+\infty)$ is well-known in mathematical fluid dynamics, because of the kinetic energy, written in terms of the linear momentum and the mass density.

Comment: For what it worth, restricting to the lines $x=ay+b$ makes the convexity question of these functions pretty clear.

Comment: @FedorPetrov. Aren't you reformulating the definition of convexity ? :)

Comment: @DenisSerre certainly I do (and apart of that just suggest a suitable parametrization: for $y=ax+b$ this is less transparent).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concrete counterexample: $p_1 = \frac 1 2 = p_2, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, b_1 = 2, b_2 = 1$. Then
$$p_1 \frac{a_1}{b_1} + p_2 \frac{a_2}{b_2} = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 2 1 = \frac 1 4 + 1 = \frac{11}{4}.$$
On the other hand,
$$\frac{p_1 a_1 + p_2 a_2}{p_1 b_1 + p_2 b_2} = 1 < \frac{11}{4}.$$